# Fastest way to add new column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What is the fastest way to add a new column to an existing table in MySQL?

I have tried `ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN ...`, but that takes quite a while since there are many rows out there.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ It's actually MariaDB. 10.1.

Comment: See also gh-ost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the fastest way in terms of getting the job done. There is no way around it directly as you have to rearrange the table structure for the new column.

If you need to keep read access to the data while the change is made but can live without write access during that time you could:

1. Create a fresh table with the extra column
2. Lock the table from updates (set all users to not have the needed permissions for instance)
3. Copy the data from old to new
4. Rename the old table to something else
5. Rename the new table to the old name
6. Drop the old table

There will still be no access at all between steps 4 and 5, and the whole process will take far longer, and of course you don't have insert/update ability during the process, but the complete outage (including reads) is only steps 4 and 5 not the whole process. As noted by ypercube in the comments, if the affected table has any foreign keys directed toward it these will need modifying and that will cause locks on the affected tables, also when creating the table (or before renaming it) make sure you include any indexes and constraints. Also any triggers operating on the old table will need to be added too (after the data has been copied).

A hacky workaround would be to put the new column(s) in a new table and just join that in to any query that needs them negating the need to modify exiting structures at all, but this means you have to be careful to update both tables correctly when needed and the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to pick up the extra values is both more work for you (and other developers on the project now and in future) and more work that the query planner/runner have to do in order to process your queries, so there are going to be performance differences.

It should go without saying: if you intend to try any of the above, as with any structural change (in fact *any* change!), do so in a testing environment first before touching production databases.

**tl;dr:** No, there isn't really a quicker way.

Comment: `RENAME TABLE old TO junk, new TO old;` is atomic and virtually instantaneous.  Doing it as two separate steps leaves you vulnerable to another process finding the table missing.

Comment: @RickJames: yes, you would want the renames to be atomic. I was assuming two statements wrapped in a transaction (can mySQL can handle DDL operations that way these days?). I didn't want to add more complexity to the answer though, when the tl;dr is "no, just do it the way you already are"!

Comment: No, DDLs still can't go in transactions (in MySQL).  Yes, you do have to stop all writes to the old table.  Otherwise, go for `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` or `pt-online-schema-change`.

Comment: Worse problem -- Your lock around the old table will have to be released before the `RENAME`.  All pending Updates/Inserts/Deletes will rush in and do their thing.  The "lock" has to be of the form of turning off all clients.

Comment: Or set `readonly=ON` and do the operations as `root` (or other `SUPER` user).  That way, any writes will abort, possibly causing a mess in the clients.

Comment: Or switch to Galera with 3 nodes, then use RSU (Rolling Schema Upgrade).  Zero downtime.  Galera is included in MariaDB 10.1.  (But you probably have only one node.)

Answer (score 1):

As for David's answer above, I assume you want the table alteration to be as fast as possible to have the shortest read/write table lock. In that case, it exists a wonderful tool from [Percona Toolkit](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/) called [`pt-online-schema-change`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html) that allows you to change the table schema without locking the table even for write access.

The internal work of the tool is pretty complex but, to make it short, if works on a copy of the table, with a trigger created on the source table to keep track of data alteration during the syncing process. Pretty brilliant, like most of the Percona tools.

It actually takes way more time than a standard `ALTER TABLE` query, for the table syncing processing between the source and the target table, but still without any read/write locks.

You should definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

"Fastest" -- Clock time, start to finish?  Or "minimal down time"?

Percona give you minimal downtime, but takes "longer".

MySQL 5.6 with `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` handles *some* alters without impacting other queries.

(It is generally bad practice to need to need to make schema changes.  But, of course, it is sometimes unavoidable.)

An alternative (zero downtime, virtually zero clock time):  Create a 'parallel' table (aka 'vertical partitioning').  It will hold the `PRIMARY KEY` of the original table, plus the new column(s).  `JOIN` the two tables when you need old and new columns at the same time.

Bonus:  If the new column is rarely populated, it can have many fewer rows than the original table.  Use `LEFT JOIN` so you can get `NULL` when the column is 'missing'.