# mysql takes too long to just add a column

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, alter-table

MySQL took 4.5 minutes to just add a column to a table having 150,000 rows.

Is there anything wrong in it or this is just normal. Is there any other alternative to fasten things?

```
ALTER TABLE job_posts
-> ADD COLUMN `is_hotlist` VARCHAR(5) NULL AFTER `msg_no`;
Query OK, 149001 rows affected (4 min 32.30 sec)
Records: 149001  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

As requested by Ergest -

```
CREATE TABLE `job_posts` (
`job_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
`description` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci,
`state` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`country` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`city` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`post_date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`msg_no` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`is_hotlist` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`),
FULLTEXT KEY `full_text` (`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=157538 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

MySQL version- 8.0.30, command `ALTER TABLE job_posts ADD COLUMN` cviews `BIGINT NULL;` almost took 5 minutes.

CPU is 8 core 16GB RAM at my local and at server it's 1 core 2GB, but time was almost the same both ways.

No foreign keys only a FT index.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to add new column in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134269/fastest-way-to-add-new-column-in-mysql)

Comment: @bbaird i thought there might be a workaround to fasten things but that answer says there's isn't, this is normal.

Answer (score 2):

It might work with algorithm instant as that is the default anyways post 8.0.12

```
ALTER TABLE job_posts ADD COLUMN `is_deleted` int NULL, ALGORITHM = INSTANT;
```

but it will not work for my case as algorithm instant does not work with tables having a full-text index as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html). It shows the error -

```
Error Code: 1846. ALGORITHM=INSTANT is not supported. Reason: InnoDB presently supports one 
FULLTEXT index creation at a time. Try ALGORITHM=COPY/INPLACE
```

Answer (score 1):

True.  It is slow.

Plan A...

The order of the columns *usually* has no impact on anything, so why include that?  I bring this up because without that clause, the `ADD COLUMN` can be 'instant', assuming also that your MySQL version is new enough.

Fails due to `FULLTEXT` index.

Plan B...

This is no faster, but, more importantly, not blocking things:  use `pt-online-schema-change` in the Percona toolkit.

Plan C...

Create another table with the new column and `job_id` (the `PRIMARY KEY`).  This will not block anything.  However, could would now change to do a `JOIN` at least for the queries that need the new column.

Bonus:  Plan C would probably allow `INSTANT` adding more columns in the future.

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya - Read the restrictions in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html -- It reads like it should have been fast.

Comment: it might work with algorithm=instant but will not work with my case as there is a full text index in my table.

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya - I added another option.

Comment: will have to do with joins rather than adding columns when rows grows to millions